# PHP MySQL SELECT WHERE statement not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I've been debugging this small amount of code for hours and cannot solve it. I am trying to find a result inside the database table where the specified username exists.

```
if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
    die("Enter a username please");
} else {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}

// check do username under that name already exists in db ?
function checker()
{
    // including username and db variables from global scope
    global $db;
    global $username;
    
    // making query
    $query = "SELECT username FROM game.usersinfo WHERE username = :username";
    $select = $db->prepare($query);
    $select->execute(['username' => $username]);
    
    return $select;
    //expected value of select is false 
}
```

// function call
checker();

The problem is due to **PHP PDO->execute()** documentation. It will throw an **object** on success and **false** on failure. I expect false to show to me, but the object always shows. There is no username in my database table that matches the username that I passed in the parameter. I tried already to use only pdo::query() method, but it didn't work.

Comment: A select statement that returns zero rows is not a failure. The query succesfully completed but found nothing. You need to check for an empty result.

Comment: @AlexHowansky . What are methods to do it ?

Comment: Call `$select->fetch()`. If it returns a row, the username was found. If not, it wasn't found.

Comment: A query failure (error) is different from a query that just failed to find any rows Check your row count, or write a query that *always* returns one row, like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`

Comment: So change it to `return $select->fetch();`

Comment: Oh , so I get it now . Query to the database is made successful ( no syntax errors or wrong column names) query did it job and returned NULL(0 rows returned under that circumstances) . I did a fetch and due to PDO::fetch() it returned me a false becuase there are no rows returned by SELECT SQL statement .

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  At the moment your code is missing vital stuff.  We cant tell if you have omitted it for brevity or whether you dont have it in your code.